# Regular expression in HTML for removing adjacent tags if pattern has been found

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an example markup here here:

```
<p>Homo Faber<span>, {{book.sales}} sales</span></p>
```

How can I find `<span>, {{book.sales}}</span>` without the outer tags?
The idea is to remove everything within the direkt tags if any `/{{ *[A-Za-z0-9.-]* *}}/` is found, but not anything beyond those.

If I would apply JavaScript:

```
document.body.innerHMTL = document.body.innerHMTL.replace(/RegExp/, "")
```

it shoult result in:

```
<p>Homo Faber</p>
```

Comment: do you want to remove all nested tags?

Comment: I want to remove the adjacent tags.